# npm packages client side with browserify

Tags: node.js, leaflet

I am trying to use the NPM package leaflet-pip for my client-side app.

In index.js

```
var lpip = require('leaflet-pip');
```

The I typed the command into my console

> browserify index.js > bundle.js

In index.html

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var mymap = L.map('map');
  function clickHandler(e) {
    mymap.eachLayer( function(overlay) {
      if(leafletPip.pointInLayer(e.latlng, overlay.feature)) {
        console.log(overlay.feature);
        console.log("Inside!");
      }
    }
  }
  mymap.on("click", clickHandler);
</script>
```

and I keep getting the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: leafletPip is not defined

Comment: You said `var lpip`, presumably `leafletPip` is not defined because that isn't what you called the variable.

Comment: the same error happens if I put `var leafletPip = require('leaflet-pip');` in index.js a re-run the browserify statement (I have also reset my cache to make sure)

Comment: also, if I look in the bundle.js file that is created by the browserify statement, there is a `var leafletPip ...` in there as well. This is why i was using `var lpip` (my troubleshooting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add leafletPip to the window object within the bundle.

so `var leafletPip = window.leafletPip = require('leaflet-pip‌​')` should work

Comment: This seems to work. Now onto other errors... like layer.eachLayer is not a function in leaflet-pip. I think I have to be passing the entire geojson object